# Setting a background resource for many linearlayouts in scrollview causes lag

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically adding around 150 linearlayouts to a scrollview in a grid-like layout. If I set the background resource to a drawable for each of them using `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x)`, the scrollview shows extremely noticeable lag and choppiness, even though the drawable is a simple colour and border.

If I remove the call to `setBackgroundResource`, the scrollview is smooth again.

Is this expected to happen with so many views containing backgrounds? If so, how would I go about making a grid with custom backgrounds for each cell?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use a list view in your scroll, and you're going to want to use a ListAdapater:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Basically what's going on is you're loading a large number of images into memory, and the scroll view by default doesn't do a very good job of managing releasing and inflating these resources.

Using methods similar to the above, with some custom image management, I've managed to get thousands of views running smoothly on a scroll.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create your own list view implementation so that you can set your own layouts for each row. I don't recommend doing this. Instead, use the default list view implementation provided by Android and instead of setting a default `ArrayAdapter` instance on the list view, subclass `ArrayAdapter`, override the `getView` method, and return your custom layout.

I highly recommend you check out this tutorial for a more thorough explanation:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429